# Android Compose positioning Composable according to another Composable position

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, mobile-development

I was trying position of my divider according to Row children's position. For that I was create a **mutableStateListOf** like this,

```
val childrenXPositions = remember { mutableStateListOf<Dp>() }
```

When I log childrenXPositions in **onGloballyPositioned** callback, I see list size as 3. But when I log in Box layout modifier it shown as empty. I was trying **LaunchedEffect** also but there is no change. Box layout modifier does not recompose. How can I achieve that? Thank you.

And here usage,

```
Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(85.dp)
            .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary.copy(alpha = 0.2f)),
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .layout { measurable, constraints ->

                    val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
                    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                        // childrenXPositions shown as empty.
                        if (childrenXPositions.isNotEmpty()) {
                            when (selectedItem) {
                                0 -> placeable.place(childrenXPositions[0].roundToPx(), 0)
                                1 -> placeable.place(childrenXPositions[1].roundToPx(), 0)
                                2 -> placeable.place(childrenXPositions[2].roundToPx(), 0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .offset(x = indicatorOffsetAnim.value)

        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(4.dp)
                    .width(50.dp)
                    .background(
                        MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                    )
            )
        }

        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        ) {
            navbarItems.forEachIndexed { index, icon ->
                NavbarButton(
                    modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                        childrenXPositions.add(it.positionInRoot().x.dp) // ADD
                 
                    },
                    selected = selectedItem == index,
                    onClick = {
                        previousItem = selectedItem
                        selectedItem = index

                    },
                    icon = icon
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to show dividers between objects in a Row, or in a Column?

Comment: Im trying show a indicator for selected navbar item. I want to set it's position to top-center of navbar button.

Comment: Maybe show a screen capture of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Okey, maybe this article can help.  https://proandroiddev.com/jetpack-compose-tutorial-animated-navigation-bar-354411c679c8
Im trying to make same behaviour of that animated navbars indicators but it's much simpler. Does my code make more sense now?